# The root of the nth matrix

Tags: roots, matrix-rank

For $n=3,$ $L$ matrix is as below:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
-1&1&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

for $n=4$ we have:

$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0\\
-1/3&-1/3&-1/3&1
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

and for $N$th we have:
$$
\left[ \begin{matrix}
1&0&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-1&1&0&0&\cdots&0&0\\
-0.5&-0.5&1&0&\cdots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots& & \vdots&\vdots\\
-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&-1/(N-2)&\cdots&1&0\\
-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&-1/(N-1)&\cdots&-1/(N-1)&0
\end{matrix} \right]
$$

How to get the roots of the $N$th order of the $L$ matrix? is there a specific logic between the roots of this matrix?

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset this in a usable form.

Comment: Hint: Your matrices are all of the form $I + B$ where $B$ is nilpotent.  If $x$ is nilpotent, the Maclaurin series for $(1+x)^{1/n}$ becomes a polynomial.